# rails layout is inheriting other layouts css?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the standard `application` layout and I have also made a `board` layout.

Application Layout `<head>`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Board Layout `<head>`:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "board", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Both layouts are found in `app/views/layouts` with filenames `application.html.erb` and `board.html.erb`

Oddly my `application` layout seems to be using the `board` layout's background color instead of it own. The font color is correct however.

Any idea what is going on here?

**Edit**

After looking further it seems `application` is also including `board`'s stylesheets. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Please show a bit more such as location of files, exact filenames, etc.

Comment: and show the content of your application.css file please

Comment: @rik.vanmechelen thanks for your comment it made me look at the application.css closer and notice the answer I just posted.

Comment: that is indeed what i expected. you can accept your own answer if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `application.css` file there is a line `*= require_tree .` which requires all other files in the same directory. So both of my CSS files were being brought into the `application` layout.

Removing `*= require_tree .` did the trick.